# send multiple values ajax jquery in the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, jqgrid, ajax.beginform

i have the next code:

```
if(jQuery('.delete').length > 0) {
jQuery('.delete').click(function(){
 var c = false;
 var cn = 0;
 var o = new Array();
 jQuery(":checked",".formerasemessage").each(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "removemessage.php",
  data: {mensajes_id: "value"}
});
  if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
      c = true;
      o[cn] = jQuery(this);
      cn++;
  }
 });
 if(!c) {
  alert('No selected message');
 } else {
  var msg = (o.length > 1)? 'messages' : 'message';
      for(var a=0;a<cn;a++) {
          jQuery(o[a]).parents('tr').remove();
      }
 }
});
}
```

and i have multiples divs, but that code only send one value repeatedly depending on the number of checkboxes to select

i want you to send me the value of each div to select, not the value of a one div repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

```
if(jQuery('.delete').length > 0) {
jQuery('.delete').click(function(){
 var c = false;
 var cn = 0;
 var o = new Array();
 jQuery(":checked",".formerasemessage").each(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "removemessage.php",
  data: {mensajes_id: jQuery(this).val()}
});
  if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
      c = true;
      o[cn] = jQuery(this);
      cn++;
  }
 });
 if(!c) {
  alert('No selected message');
 } else {
  var msg = (o.length > 1)? 'messages' : 'message';
      for(var a=0;a<cn;a++) {
          jQuery(o[a]).parents('tr').remove();
      }
 }
});
}
```

you can use `$(this).val()` to get the current node value easlly